# jQuery(...).prettyPhoto is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, prettyphoto

I've run into an issue where prettyPhoto and the menus for the WordPress plugin WPGYM conflict. The output from the Chrome console is below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).prettyPhoto is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:3)
at i (jquery.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)
```

Based on this information I've tracked the issue to this line from script.js:-

```
jQuery(".gallery-icon a").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'normal',theme:'light_square', show_title : false}); jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto'], .gallery-icon a").prettyPhoto({animationSpeed:'normal',theme:'light_square', show_title : false});
```

As I'm not really familiar with Jquery I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: prettyPhoto is included? After jQuery?

Comment: do you added the prettyPhoto library? Put your html+jquery code completely .so that we can help. BTW you have to add first jquery library then prettyPhoto library and then your script code to make it work

Comment: There may be option in plugin in which include pretty photo jquery at footer, it makes jquery load before pretty photo jquery.Make sure jquery is being loaded as well.

Comment: I am having the same issue, if someone can solve  this will be great.

Comment: Okay, finally had a chance to get back to this.

Firstly, none of what's been written here helps.